# using jquery to determine total file size

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I define the file as a variable with  jquery selector I get this error :
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined. if I use :

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');
```

instead of

`var file = $('#file').val();`

then it works, but I'm curious why using jquery selector doen't work. Thanks

```
$('#file').on('change', function(){

  var file = $('#file').val();
      var sizes = [].map.call(file.files, function(v) {return v.size;});
      var totalSize = sizes.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;}, 0);
 });
```

Comment: i would assume because `val` is going to give you the string value of the input, not a DomNode which is what getElementById will give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery selector `$("#element")` returns a jquery object not an actual dom element.

You can test this yourself by opening up the console in chrome or firebug, and selecting an element with jquery.

Also `$('file').val()` is a function for returning the value of a dom element that has a value attribute.

If you want to use jquery to select but need to manipulate the dom element and not the jquery object, you need to do this:

```
var file = $('#file')[0];
```

Which will retrieve the dom node from the jquery object.

Comment: @user2014429 yep, been burned by that myself once or twice before. First time I ran into it took me forever to track down why I couldn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`val` returns the name of the selected files, you should use `files` property of the `InputElement` object.

```
$('#file').on('change', function(){
    var size = 0;
    $.each(this.files, function(i, v){
       size += v.size
    })
 });
```

Please note that IE browsers do not support `files` property.